# any third party tool available for multiple file uploads

Tags: c#, asp.net

For ASP.NET any third party tool available for **multiple file uploads** which is free.Plz also mention the pros and cons of that tool.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why a third party tool?  Why not just coded directly in asp .net?  Pros: You control the code and can customize it to your heart's content.  Cons: You have to write code.

Comment: If u r telling about ASP.NET code,FYI in ASP.NET u can't directly select multiple files and upload them..Thats the problem we are facing in our project :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side you can use the [this](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) jquery plugin to select the multiple files and post them.

On the client side you can just use the HTML on the sample page.
Set the action of the form tag to point to the page that will handle the posted files.

You could do something like this if your target for your post is going to be an ashx page.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    HttpFileCollection hfc = context.Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        {   
            string imageLocation = "C:\\ImageLocation\\" + theFileNameToSaveAs;

            hpf.SaveAs(imageLocation);
        }
    }
    context.Response.Redirect("../callingpage.aspx"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) or uploadfive - I am currently using it on my project

- **PROS**: Easy to use and implement
- **CONS**: Some issues with IE9